# What does it mean "predictive attribute"?

Tags: r, statistics, data-mining, data-analysis

I've downloaded a [data set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Computer+Hardware) from UCI Machine Learning Repository. In the description of the data set, they talk about "predictive attribute" and "non-predictive attribute". What does it mean and how can you identify them in a data set?
[image: Description of the attribute]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks like attributes relates to type of data points available; therefore a predictive attribute would be a data point that can be used to "predict" something, such as `MYCT`, `MMIN`, `MMAX`, `CACH`, `CHMIN`, `CHMAX`.  The "non-predictive attribute" would be the vendor names and model name.  PRP seems to be the goal field, and linear regression guess is ERP.

Comment: So if i understand well, they try to predict the ERP with the 6 predictive attributes ?

Comment: @djohon Yes, I assume so.  I couldn't find any solid references for a definition, but just looking at the variables tells something.

Comment: Yeah, i was also looking for a valid definition since there was none after my google searches. thanks

Comment: @djohon This would be my guess.  Please upvote and accept answer if it is satisfactory for you.

Answer (score 1):

Predictive attribute are attributes that *may* help your prediction.

Non-predictive attributes are known to not help. For example, a record id, user number, etc. Unique keys usually fall into this category.